# Export Plone content based on a catalog search (quintagroup.transmogrifier)

Tags: plone, data-migration, plone-4.x, transmogrifier

In my Plone 4 site, I have installed `quintagroup.transmogrifier` (I tried both release `0.5` and the bleeding-edge github version) and `collective.transmogrifier` 1.5.

I found an example for an export based on a `portal_catalog` search [here](http://opensourcehacker.com/2010/12/27/importing-and-exporting-plone-folders-using-quintagroup-transmogrify/).

I have the following export configuration, registered as `catalogsearch`:

```
[transmogrifier]
pipeline =
    catalog
    fileexporter
    marshaller
    datacorrector
    portletsexporter
    writer
    EXPORTING

[catalog]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.catalogsource
path = query= /Plone/some/existing/folder/

[fileexporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.fileexporter

[marshaller]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.marshaller

[datacorrector]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.datacorrector
sources =
    marshall

[portletsexporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.portletsexporter

[writer]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.writer
prefix = structure

[EXPORTING]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.logger
keys =
    _type
    _path
```

The idea is to specify the search expression when calling the transmogrifier:

```
$ bin/instance debug
>>> portal = app.Plone
>>> from collective.transmogrifier.transmogrifier import Transmogrifier
>>> tm = Transmogrifier(portal)
>>> tm('catalogsearch')
>>> tm('catalogsearch', catalog={'path': '/Plone/some/existing/folder/'})
```

However, both calls to the `Transmogrifier` object **never return**; I need to terminate them with `Ctrl+C`.
Shouldn't this work, regardless of the `debug` session?
What is wrong?

Comment: I can only suggest using collective.jsonmigrator instead.  See [my blog article on the subject](http://www.jowettenterprises.com/blog/plone-content-migration-using-transmogrifier-and-collective.jsonify)

Comment: What I like about the export/import solution: It gives me a selective backup solution as well. However, I meanwhile wrote a browser to access the functionality, and there I see the export running. Next problem: how do I get the generated tarball ...